# How to debug these errors in an Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm doing a stored procedure and it gives me the following errors, I do not understand how I can solve them

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ERROR;
/

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_VENTA_MEN;    
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_ventas
--(P_FECHA DATE , P_CONTADOR NUMBER , P_TOTAL NUMBER)
IS
   CURSOR vent_cur
   IS
      SELECT * FROM vendedor;

   v_fecha         DATE := TO_CHAR (022018, 'MM/YYYY');

   v_contador      NUMBER := 0;

   v_total_men     NUMBER := 0;

   v_boleta        NUMBER (9);

   v_total         NUMBER (9);

   v_men_errores   VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN
   FOR reg_vent IN vent_cur
   LOOP
      SELECT v.id_vendedor,
             b.fecha_boleta,
             b.nro_boleta,
             v.sueldo_base
        INTO v_boleta, v_total
        FROM vendedor v JOIN boleta b ON (v.id_vendedor = b.id_vendedor)
       WHERE v.id_vendedor = reg_vent.id_vendedor;

      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO ventas_mensuales
              VALUES (seq_venta_men.NEXTVAL,
                      reg_vent.id_vendedor,
                      v_fecha,
                      v_boleta,
                      reg_vent.sueldo_base);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            v_men_errores := slerrm;

            INSERT INTO reg_errores
                 VALUES (seq_error.NEXTVAL, 'SP_VENTAS', v_men_errores);
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Errors:

```
Error(39,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(40,25): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
Error(48,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(48,13): PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
Error(55,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(55,18): PLS-00201: identifier 'SLERRM' must be declared
```

Comment: The error message pretty clear - what exactly is it you don't understand about them?

Answer (score 4):

- *First Error*  : In the SELECT list, there are 4 items, while INTO has 2(should be 4)
- *Second Error* : It seems table *VENTAS_MENSUALES* has less than 5 columns
- *Third Error*  : not *SLERRM* but *SQLERRM*.

Moreover, This assignment `V_FECHA DATE := TO_CHAR(022018 , 'MM/YYYY');` is problematic, that might be :

`V_FECHA VARCHAR2(7) := TO_CHAR(sysdate , 'MM/YYYY');`

or
`V_FECHA VARCHAR2(7) := '02/2018';`